# Отличие результатов метода count класса Builder и метода count класса Collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Наткнулся на интересный результат, который не смог объяснить сам.

Есть запрос:

```
$a = $this->payment_repository->query()
        ->selectRaw('distinct(y)')
        ->where([
            ['x', '>', 0],
            ['y', '>', 0],
            ['y', '<>', DB::raw('x')],
            'z' => 'u2u',
        ])
        ->whereIn('b', [1, 4]);
```

Так вот, если получать количество строк такими способами:

```
$a->count();//6
$a->get()->count(); //5
```

получаются разные результаты.

Если аналогичный запрос выполнять в СУБД, то правильный результат будет 5.

Подскажите, почему метод Builder возвращает неправильный результат?

Comment: В первом случае у вас выборка из БД, во втором - первый подходящий результат. Само собой они будут различаться

Comment: Прошу прощения, скопировал код, который уже решает проблему. Обновил код в соответствии с тем, что я имел в виду в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [count()](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_count) билдера имеет параметр $columns, который по умолчанию равен '*'. Поэтому, если вызвать его без параметра, вы получите значение `select count(*)` вместо того, что у вас было указано в билдере ранее.

Чтобы получить то, что вы хотите, нужно вызвать этот метод таким образом:

```
$a->count(DB::raw('distinct(y)'))
```

Answer (score 0):

По моим предположениям $a->count() заменяет SELECT distinct(y) на SELECT count(*), из-за чего происходит неправильный подсчет.

Как решение сделал ->selectRaw('count(distinct(y)) as count'), и затем брал вот так: $a->first()->count

Comment: Метод count() билдера имеет параметр $columns. То есть вы можете получить желаемое и таким образом: `$a->count(DB::raw('distinct(y)'))`

Comment: Да, я не додумался, что так можно, спасибо!)
Оформите как ответ, и я отмечу его как правильный

Comment: Оформил как ответ